# How disable / Enable rechatcha based on uncheck or check from checkbox

Tags: javascript, php

I want to disable/enable rechatcha based on uncheck/check from checkbox if unchecked then rechatcha should be disabled; if checked then rechatcha can checklist.

This is my code with checkbox and rechatcha

```
<input type="checkbox" name="check2" value=""> Saya Menyatakan Bahwa Data   Adalah Benar<br/></h5></B>
<div class="form-group">
 <div  class="col-sm-4">
  <div class="g-recaptcha" nama = "capcay" id ="capcay" data-sitekey="6LfmhHQUAAAAAIhfG-Vhiq4FN1_VPGgARvtlmWsA">
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Did'nt test is, but maybe you can use JavaScript to just hide it? `document.getElementsById("captcha").setAttribute("style", "display:none;"); ` (don't forget to also give the ID captcha to the proper element.

Comment: not work for me :(

Comment: How did you try it?

Comment: i try  document.getElementById("captcha").disabled = false;

Comment: That is not what I asked you to do, right? ;) 
I'm almost sure that Google does not include the disabled property in reCaptcha. My solutions just hides it from the screen, maybe you need to trigger it with a [onclick](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp)?

Comment: yeah i try it but failed :(

Comment: thank you my problem was solved

Comment: Did my solution help? I can add it as answer and you can mark it as solution ;)

Comment: ok sure thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did'nt test it, but maybe you can use JavaScript to just hide it? `document.getElementsById("captcha").setAttribute("style", "display:none;");`
 (don't forget to also give the ID captcha to the proper element.